# Using constexpr to replace #define and #ifdef for conditional compilation

Tags: c++, constants, c++17, constexpr

I am trying to replace the preprocessor #define and #if/#ifdef's that I am using to control conditional compilation with constexpr variables and ifs.

Is it possible to declare constexpr variables such that they reproduce the #defines in that they don't allocate runtime storage, and that taking the address of one leads to a compile time error?

### Edited to add code example.

So in the headers I want to have something like

```
namespace ExampleNamespace
{
  enum class Platform : int {Darwin, Linux, Windows};

  constexpr Platform BuildPlatform = Platform::Darwin;  // Line A.
};
```

While in the code I want

```
if constexpr (Platform::Darwin == BuildPlatform)        // Line B.
  {
    cout << "Platform is Darwin" << endl;
  }
else
  {
    cout << "Platform is not Darwin" << endl;
  };

const Platform *const PlatformAddress = &BuildPlatform; // Line C.
const Platform &BuildPlatform2 = BuildPlatform;         // Line D.
```

Then aim is then to change the definition of BuildPlatform on Line A, such that Line B is evaluated at compile time (and the else clause gets discarded/not compiled) and lines C and D (and anything that does the same thing, or relies on runtime storage for BuildPlatform) generates a compiler error.

Is such a construct possible in C++17?

Comment: Give code example, as is, it is too broad.

Comment: [This](https://blog.tartanllama.xyz/if-constexpr/) might help

Comment: Address is relatively easy to block (barring use of `std::addressof`), but reference is difficult and it also causes ODR-existence.  Are your variables integer constants or floating point values or what exactly?

Comment: constexpr can not help you with conditional existence of variables, for example I do not want to have int x; if I am on Windows... while preprocessor can.

Comment: @Jarod42 Added code example.

Comment: @138 Thanks for the link, I had not come across this one on my hunt, but I don't think it get's me to a point where I'm sure I will have no runtime storage allocated, or have I missread/missunderstod something in the link?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Yes, I guess there are a lot of ways around anything I try to do in the core language, and maybe I am better sticking to the preprocessor for some of this, but there seems to be a general feeling that all preprocessor magic is evil (I've been away from C++ for about 10 years, I don't remember this being the case when I was still working in industry) but it's not clear to me that I can cover all the cases with constexpr. I've a mix of ints, floats and flags that I'm trying to shift over to c++17.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl, I don;t have any cases at the moment where I have conditionaly dependent variables, these ar already covered by having anything that platform specific in different header files, and just picking up the right set.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

For flags and integers, enum values work.

For floating point values, there is no constexpr way that guarantees no ODR usage.  ODR usage tends to cause storage to be created for the constant.

You could use a constexpr function that returns a floating point value, but the function could easily take storage.

Comment: No, it is not possible. see [the other answer][https://stackoverflow.com/a/52441995/476681]

Answer (score 6):

It is partially possible:

```
if constexpr (Platform::Darwin == BuildPlatform) {        // Line B.
    std::cout << "Platform is Darwin" << std::endl;
} else {
    std::cout << "Platform is not Darwin" << std::endl;
}
```

but as `template <typename T> void foo() {static_assert(false);}` is ill formed,
code of all branches should have some kind of validity.

```
#ifdef (DarwinPlatform) // constexpr cannot be used here, you have to 
                        //rely on MACRO here
# include <darwin.h>     // Some OS specific header
#endif

void foo()
{
    if constexpr (Platform::Darwin == BuildPlatform) {
        DarwinMethod(); // Won't compile on other platforms as
                        // the method doesn't exist.
        // you should make the block template with template dependent code
        // to allow code to compile.
        // as http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c695575e4dcdecee
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this.

```
enum class Platform { Darwin, Linux, Windows };

#ifdef __darwin__
constexpr Platform  BuildPlatform = Platform::Darwin;
#elif __linux__
constexpr Platform  BuildPlatform = Platform::Linux;
#elif __WIN32
constexpr Platform  BuildPlatform = Platform::Windows;
#endif

// your code then uses it like this

if constexpr (BuildPlatform == Platform::Darwin) 
{         
}
else if constexpr (BuildPlatform == Platform::Linux)
{
}
else if constexpr (BuildPlatform == Platform::Windows)
{   
}
```